# Get rid of scrollbar in a fixed-width/fluid mixed layout

Tags: html, css, layout, fluid-layout

My problem is demonstrated by this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/pschyska/HAPLU/

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="header">header</div>
  <div class="navigation">nav<br>nav<br><nav<br>nav<br></nav<br></div>
  <div class="col1 col-collapsed">col1<br><br></div>
  <div class="dynamic">
    <div class="col2 col-large">
        col2<br><br>col2<br><br>col2<br><br>col2<br><br>col2<br><br>
        col2<br><br>col2<br><br>col2<br><br>col2<br><br>col2<br><br>
        col2<br><br>col2<br><br>col2<br><br>col2<br><br>col2<br><br>
        col2<br><br>col2<br><br>col2<br><br>col2<br><br>col2<br><br>
        col2<br><br>col2<br><br>col2<br><br>col2<br><br>col2<br><br>
        col2<br><br>col2<br><br>col2<br><br>col2<br><br>col2<br><br>
        col2<br><br>col2<br><br>col2<br><br>col2<br><br>col2<br><br>
        col2<br><br>col2<br><br>col2<br><br>col2<br><br>col2<br><br>
        col2<br><br>col2<br><br>col2<br><br>col2<br><br>col2<br><br>
        col2<br><br>col2<br><br>col2<br><br>col2<br><br>col2<br><br>
    </div>
    <div class="col3 col-large">col3</div>
  </div>
</div>

 .header {
   height: 20px;
 }

 .main {
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
 }

 .main .navigation {
   position: absolute;
   height: 100%;
   width: 50px;
 }

 .main .col-collapsed {
   position: absolute;
   left: 50px;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100px;
   overflow-x: hidden;    
   overflow-y: auto;
 }

 .main .dynamic {
   margin-left: 150px;
   height: 100%;
 }

 .main .col-large {
   height: 100%;
   width: 50%;
   float: left;
   overflow-x: hidden;    
   overflow-y: auto;

 }

 .main {
   background-color: #5555ee;
 }

 .header {
   color: white;
   background-color: black;
 }

 .navigation {
   background-color: blue;
 }

 .col1 {
   background-color: #aaaa00;
 }

 .col2 {
   background-color: #00ffbb;
 }

 .col3 {
   background-color: #ff00bb;
 }

 .dynamic {
   background-color: #5af00a;
 }
```

I need the header to be fixed height, and the first 2 columns (`.navigation`, `.col1`) to be fixed width. The next 2 columns should share the remaining horizontal space evenly.
All 4 columns `.navigation`, `.col1`, `.col2`, `.col3` must be "100%", actually "100% minus header-height". I didn't get his to work. The columns height is always equal to the document height, and I get a vertical scrollbar the same size as header height.

Bonus: I don't like that nested `.dynamic` attribute at all. It's just boilerplate without semantic. Is there another way to do it? Without it, the columns would take 50% of the document's width, not 50% of the remaining space each.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

y dont u  try tables. Here is the raw structure in your case. Use width attribute for td's for which you want fixed width. rest of the both will equally share the remaining space.

```
    <div>
<table style="width:100%" border="1">
    <thead>
    <th colspan="4">This is header</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td width="10%">col1</td>
    <td width="20%">col2</td>
    <td>col3</td>
    <td>col4</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I dont wanna use a table, because it's not tabular data I'm going to display :-) I'm considering it as a last resort though.